# How to export from 3DSMAX to FBX with tangents and texture coords

Tags: xna, 3dsmax, fbx

I bought a model from TurboSquid in 3DS format and am trying to load it into an XNA project.

I've exported to FBX and turned ON the "Tangents and Binormals" export options.

If I do not set basicEffect.TexturesEnabled, it renders but without textures.  If I turn on TexturesEnabled, though, I have problems:

If I turn off "Generate Tangent Frames" in the content processor, I get "The current vertex declaration does not include all the elements required by the current vertex shader. TextureCoordinate0 is missing." at runtime.

If I turn on "Generate Tangent Frames" in the content processor, I get "Required Vertex Channel TextureCoordinate0 no found" at build time.

So, the question is how to take a model in 3DS, export it so I can use it as an FBX model in XNA and get all of the UV mapping and normals correct.  Even the VS2012 FBX preview can render it properly, so it seems like it should have all it needs, but no.

Answer (score 2):

This can be a number of things. If the model was using a 3rd party plugin or materials other than standard, this will cause the UVs not to align.

My suggestion is to make sure that the materials are in a standard format
Ungroup the entire model if necessary.

lastly,
If the model is not rigged, make sure it's an editable poly.

From there you can try and export the model again. Are there any other formats that XNA can import?

If this doesn't help, please go to Support.TurboSquid.com and create a support ticket. We can try our best to help.

Christopher Briere

TurboSquid Product Support